# Closing Shopify online store sales channel after moving to storefront API

Tags: shopify, storefront, shopify-storefront-api

I recently changed a Shopify store to use a separate SPA using the storefront API. However the old 'online store' is still running as a separate website with some theme plugins etc. I'd like to remove this sales channel now that I'm using a custom app and the storefront API so that customers aren't confused as to why there are two websites running concurrently. However, when going to remove my online store, Shopify prompts me with an 'are you sure' modal that contains a warning that I won't be able to publish products and that they will send a request to a developer to delete personal customer information.

Obviously this is not what I want as the store is still running through storefront API and I still need everything on the Shopify admin side to remain intact and running. I tried getting support from Shopify about it but they just pointed me in the direction of the developer documentation. It's not really clear what impact deleting this sales channel would have? Any advice from someone who's done something similar would be greatly appreciated.

[image]